# How modify a class attribute through a reference of it?

Tags: python, class, reference, attributes

For exemple in the below example:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1.

class essai():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C = myClass()

    def ref(self):

        mystring = 'C.A'
        nameclass, nameparam = mystring.split('.')
        print(nameclass, nameparam)
        print(getattr(getattr(self,nameclass),nameparam))
        Ref = getattr(getattr(self,nameclass),nameparam)
        print(Ref)
        self.modify_val(Ref,2)
        print(self.C.A)

    def modify_val(self,x,y):
        x=y


E=essai()
E.ref()
```

What I would like to do is getting the reference to the attribut `A` of the `C` class in `essai`. The point is I would like to use that reference to update the value of `C.A` in the method `modify_val`. By using a string that contains the class and the attribute I want modify (`mystring = 'C.A'`), I don't understand how I can get a reference to that attribute (`C.A` for instance) and how I can use that reference to modify the attribute. In my example, `modify_val` function don't update the `C.A` value because `Ref` is not acually a reference.
Therefore I get :

```
C A
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

I would like the last print to be 2

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `setattr(object, name, value)`

From the python documentation for [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#setattr)

> setattr(object, name, value)
>
> This is the counterpart of getattr(). The arguments are an object, a
>   string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing
>   attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the
>   attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, setattr(x,
>   'foobar', 123) is equivalent to x.foobar = 123.

by passing `nameclass` and `nameparam` directly to `modify_val` you should be able to do something like this:

```
def modify_val(self, nameclass, nameparam, value)
    setattr(getattr(self,nameclass),nameparam, value)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I cannot use setattr. I want update attributes of class within numba njit functions. to do so, I need to pass the reference to the attribute like I do for methods. like if i have a ref=essai.modify_val will give me a reference that I can pass to the njit function. but I cannot do this with attributes.

Comment: Ok. I don't know about numba in particular but I found an answer talking about parameter references in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/2381553). It suggests to look at parameters as references all the time but some will be mutable and others immutable.